# Cannot bind multiple parameters using call_user_func_array()

Tags: php, mysqli

I know they're many, many questions already about this, but I have no idea why mine doesn't work.

If I just use the following, my code works fine:
$this->stmt->bind_param("ii", $params[0], $params[1]);

But if I use the call_user_func_array, it breaks. One suggestion I got was passing the $parameters array by reference, but adding an & before the variable also broke my code...

Any help is greatly recieved!

Here's my code:

DB class:

```
function selectQuery($sql, $paramTypes = false, $params = false) {
        //Prepare statement
        $this->stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);

        if($this->stmt === false) {
            //We have an error
            echo 'Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $this->conn->error;
        }

        //This part doesn't work...

        // if ($params) {
        //  //Bind an unknown number of parameters
        //  $parameters = array_merge(array($paramTypes), $params);

        //  call_user_func_array(array($this->stmt, 'bind_param'), $parameters);
        // }

        //This works.

        $this->stmt->bind_param("ii", $params[0], $params[1]);

        //Execute statement
        $this->stmt->execute();

        if ($this->stmt->error) {
            echo $this->stmt->error;
            return false;
        }

        //Get the results
        $result = $this->stmt->get_result();

        $data = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        //Close statement
        $this->stmt->close();

        //Return the results
        return $data;
    }
```

Test page:

```
<?php
require_once('DatabaseAccess.php');

$db = new DB();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ? OR id = ?";

echo "Fetching data....<br>";
$result = $db->selectQuery($sql, "ii", array(1, 2));

foreach($result as $r) {
    echo "<pre>".print_r($r, 1)."</pre>";
}
?>
```

Decided to add more information:

I'll be using this function to pass in the parameter types and parameters, but the amount will vary. When I looked up how to do this everyone suggested the call_user_func thing, but each time I try it (tried a few different ways) it won't work. Read through many threads, but it never seems to work. If I just use the bind_params function directly it works and I get the correct data returned.

Using the call_user_func thing I was getting the no data for the ? mysqli error, which is when I tried passing by reference and the code just broke completely...

Comment: How you use the call_user_func_array() and how you pass params into this function?

Comment: The params are passed from the test page, code is above. The call_user_func_array() is also in the code above, in the DB Class section (it's commented out)

Comment: you cant pass parameters by reference - that's written in documentation; so try this. mb this will help you
$res = array();
foreach($parameters as $key => $value) {$res[$key] = &$parameters[$key];}

Comment: Could you expand on that a little in an answer? I'm really not understanding all of this at the moment :(

Comment: I've got it working using you're code. Thank you! If you put it in an answer I can mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it before call_user_func_array()

```
$res = array();
foreach($parameters as $key => $value) {
    $res[$key] = &$parameters[$key];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)